# How to get only the different fields

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have two objects of a class.

I need to compare each field with the other, and if the data is different to make certain actions

```
class A
{
    int id;
    string text;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return  id; }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return  text; }
    }
}
```

as I see it:

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = aObj.different(bObj);

list.Key - name property
list.Value - value of the bObj if it is different
```

Comment: What is your question?  This doesn't really make what you are trying to do clear.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: That seems reasonable enough. What's the question? :)

Comment: I think he simply needs to compare the property data of two classes which are the same.  At least I assume they are the same

Comment: @griegs, Yes aObj and bObj this is object as class A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetDifferences(A target)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> differences = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(A).GetProperties())
    {
        if (!pi.GetValue(this, null).Equals(pi.GetValue(target, null)))
            differences.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(target, null));
    }
    return differences;
}
```

Comment: +1.  Actually @simply denis, this is pretty good.  You need to add your second class to this and compare, or write and extension method but returning the differences is excellent

Comment: But you'll get an exception if you get any property = null in your  source object, or target == null, so make sure to validate that.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write a helper that uses reflection to get the properties of both objects, loops through them and compares the values 1 to 1.

[This might help you](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Getallpropertiesfromaclass.htm)

[And this one too](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information)

**edit**

i think it'd be easier if both your objects implemented the same interface too.

Comment: A helper which receives two selectors (Func<T1,T2>) can be used simplifying the solution, loosing a bit of performance but keeping it reusable.

Comment: Yeah using reflection will slow things down a bit.  Hopefully @Simply denis does not need to do this 1,000 a minute :)

Answer (score 1):

Make Class A : IComparable and define the logic for CompareTo()

Then you can use A.CompareTo.  The benefit is you can then use this in List<> if you need to sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a lot of different manners. The best one deppends of the length of your lists of attributes. The simplest way is iterate over a first list, and for each item, iterate over the second one and try to identify if they are differents.

For large lists (>20), with similar sizes (+/- 20%) you should sort the two lists, iterate over both identifying matching items.

For large lists with discrepant lengths you can build a dictionary with the larger list, iterating over the smaller looking for the matching item on the previous built dictionary.